# An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

This error appears in my case in PHP Symfony4 /PDO Doctrine with MySql 8.0.13 Server when I try to connect to Database:

> An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Answer (score 26):

You have to use legacy style passwords for MySQL 8 and PHP7+:

```
ALTER USER 'username'@'ip_address' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Comment: I was trying with `'root'@'127.0.0.1'` getting error. But then I tried `'root'@'localhost'` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

So, here’s the fix. You can create a user with the “old” authentication mechanisme, which the MySQL database driver for PHP still expects.

```
CREATE USER 'ohdear_ci'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'ohdear_secret';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ohdear_ci.* TO 'ohdear_ci'@'localhost';
```

If you already have an existing user with permissions on databases, you can modify that user instead.

```
ALTER USER 'ohdear_ci'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'ohdear_secret';
```

After that, your PHP code can once again connect to MySQL 8.

[Reference Link](https://ma.ttias.be/mysql-8-laravel-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-client/)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the directive in your mysql configuration :

```
[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Comment: Please elaborate why this solution should be used.

Comment: @Xanlantos so you wouldn't have to specify it every time you create / update a user with mysql. It would be set as default.